# ¿Como borrar el cacheado del TAG AUDIO?

Tags: javascript, html5, audio-manager

Saludos estimados alguien sabe como borrar el cacheado del tag audio, con javascript.

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Genero un Audio mp3 y lo cargo en mi etiqueta AUDIO.
pero según otro evento genero otro Audio con el mismo nombre, pero cuando lo reproduzco sigue el primer audio.

EL archivo mp3 se genero de manera correcta.
Las rutas son correctas.

Answer (score 0):

La manera rápida y furiosa de obligar a JavaScript a no cachear un asset es modificando su URL. Si estás creando tu audio así:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'tu_archivo.mp3';
```

Podés modificarlo así:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = 'tu_archivo.mp3?aleatorio=' + Math.random();
```

Eso obliga al navegador a cargar el archivo desde el servidor cada vez.